# DataBinding Grid with data from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data structure(bindingList)that receives data from a another thread with I've bound to a dataGridView which is throwing a cross thread exception. how do I invoke a dataGridView which is dataBound? This is a winForm project. Here's an example of what I'm talking about for clarity:

```
DataStore dStore = new DataStore();
dStore.ReceiveData += new ReceiveDataEventHndlr(data);
BindingList<mydataobj> myDataStructure = new BindingList<mydataobj>();
dataGridView.DataSource = myDataStructure;

// here's my cross threading issue
private void data(string s, double d)
{
    myDataStructure.Add(new MyDataObj(s,d));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) when modifying Controls from another thread:

```
private void data(string s, double d)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(new Action( () => {data(s, d);} ));
        return;
    }
    myDataStructure.Add(new MyDataObj(s,d));
}
```

First, you check to see if [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx). If so, then call `Invoke()` with a delegate to the same function, and then return.  It will re-enter the function from the GUI thread, `InvokeRequired` will be `false`, and the control will be updated.

Comment: oh ok...i didn't know that invoking on dataStructure would resolve this. i thought i had to invoke the dataGridView

Comment: No, you do. You I call Invoke on the control (dataGridView)

Comment: i'm not understaning. maybe i should clarify more: my dataGridView is in my presentation tier (GUI). myDataStructure and dStore are within my businss logic tier (BAL). my dStore and myDataStructure don't interact with my dataGridView other than through dataBinding...passing myDataStructre to the GUI for binding and that's it.

Comment: hey thx for the solution. i understanding it now. yeah, that example you gave me is the correct way to go about it. thx again!

Comment: the example is also a clean and update ".NET advised" approach by using LINQ and the generic delegate. thx once again!

Comment: hey, one other question: what if myDataStructure and dStore are in another class separate from my dataGridView? how would I go about binding? myDataStructure would be popluated by dStore event (void data()) in another class. how would I bind myDataStructure to my dataGridView?

Comment: Just use that reentrant InvokeRequired code, but instead of this, use your dataGridView object